# Json serialization returns: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, rest, flutter-listview

So I'm trying to build a list (of any kind) from a Json list object in flutter, I'm getting it using REST api the response is a Json list with the fields: type, contact {first_name, last_name}, created_at, uuid.

using this code I'm fetching the data and parsing it to custom data type

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:connectix/models/calls.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class ContactService {
static String _url = "https://api.voipappz.io/tasks//connectix_conversations_recent";

static Future browse() async{
var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(_url));

}
}

List<CallType> parseCalls(String responseBody) {
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

return parsed.map<CallType>((json) => CallType.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<CallType>> fetchCalls(http.Client client) async {
final response = await client
  .get(Uri.parse("https://api.voipappz.io/tasks//connectix_conversations_recent"));
// Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
return compute(parseCalls, response.body);
}
```

That's the data type model

```
class CallType {
final String type;
final String first_name, last_name;
final String created;

CallType({
required this.type,
required this.first_name,
required this.last_name,
required this.created,
});

factory CallType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
return CallType(
  type: json['type'],
  first_name: json['contact.first_name'],
  last_name: json['contact.last_name'],
  created: json['created_at'],
);
} 

}
```

and this is the code for the widget I'm trying to display and returns me the error in the question title

```
class CallsList extends StatelessWidget {
final List<CallType> calls;

CallsList({Key? key, required this.calls}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: calls.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text(calls[index].type);
  },
);
}
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('hello'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder<List<CallType>>(
      future: fetchCalls(http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

      return snapshot.hasData
          ? CallsList(calls: snapshot.data!)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You marked all attributes of `CallType` as `required`. It looks like the API is not returning data for one (or more) of these attributes.

You need either to mark them as optional (remove `required` and make them of type `String?`), or take care that your API is always responding with data.

Comment: Iv'e commented out the first_name and last_name and the error gone away. maybe I'm doing something wrong when trying to go to key contact.last_name?
the json is contact : { first_name: XXX, last_name: XXX}

Comment: I think `json['contact.first_name']`does not work.
Try `json['contact']['first_name']`.